# Does TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation ever happen with a Task.Factory task?

Tags: c#, task

Does this ever happen with a Task created by Task.Factory?  I see it all the time with my async tasks, but I've never seen it on a Task.Factory task.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2009/08/30/the-meaning-of-taskstatus/

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko, I have a doubt. usually task runs on a available thread in thread pool. If the pool is busy the task is placed in Queue (FIFO).  And the task is not scheduled as the thread is not available in the pool.  In this case, what will be the enum status? Is it "WaitingForActivation". If the task is scheduled and waiting probably it  is "WaitingToRun" rt?

Comment: As far as I can see from reference source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,79588e534a82b826 the fact that the pool is busy doen't affect the task status; `WaitingForActivation` is for continuation tasks: `internal void TaskConstructorCore(...)` For continuation tasks or TaskCompletionSource.Tasks, begin life in the WaitingForActivation state rather than the Created state. `tmpFlags |= TASK_STATE_WAITINGFORACTIVATION;`